# display the mysql count function?

Tags: php, mysql, function, count

```
$query = "select count(*)
                      from relationships
                      where leader = 'user_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
```

how can i display the count? thanks

Comment: plus i want to display it even if its zero :)) thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $count[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$num_rows = $values['total']; 
echo $num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` and access it by index 0: $row[0]
2. use an alias in your query ("select count(*) as cnt from ...") and `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` and access it by name: $row['cnt']

Answer (score 0):

```
$abc="SELECT count(*) as c FROM output WHERE question1=4";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$abc);
if($result)
{
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
        echo $row['c'];
  }     

}
```

Its work completely in this it count the number of occurrences of 4 in the column

Comment: this question has already answered in 2010! why do you keep giving answer to old question that has already mark as corrected answer?

Comment: because that your given code is not working with my problem i tried a lot but its not works that's why i post right code here for clarification  if any one wants its